# Transparent proxy with php

Tags: php

I'm looking to code a transparent proxy for several users on a single website. My code is based on this script :
http://code.google.com/p/php-transparent-proxy/source/browse/proxy.php?r=1

It does what i need after few tweaks, but with my host, it doesnt work anymore when it requires to login into the targeted website. It acts like I don't send the $_POST array.

It's working fine with WAMP on my computer so i guess it's related to my host configuration.

Is there an easy way to know what's preventing the script to work? Or any other way to go through this problem.

The phpinfo is here :
http://php.goldzoneweb.info/

PS : the goal of this proxy is that the user log on it, it connects to the target website and display differently the page, and stores / gets things on a database.

Comment: probly not a good idea to expose your `phpinfo()` for the world to see.. just saying

Comment: the phpinfo is available on my free host website. IT's the basic one provided with free account, and i can't change it.